# Responsive CSS Type scaling based on longest word in a list

Tags: css

I'm getting familiar with `vmin vh` etc
but I need a mroe elegant solution to display a list of words say:

```
apple
banana
lemon
pineapple
```

so the list takes always the maximum width of thew viewport...based on the longest word in this case '`pineapple`'

using just CSS is it possible?

Comment: not sure if I understand, something like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/QMEyMW

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list element to always take *x* width of a page while keeping the elements boundaries fluid as to expand around its content ( instead of a fixed width ) you could use a solution that combines an `inline-block` display with a `vw` unit on the `font-size` of the `html` element. This, however scales everything in the entire page accordingly.

*( make full-screen and resize the page to see the list adapt )*

```js
// All javascript is necessary only for the button to demo list growth.
function addCnt(){
  var pinapl = document.getElementById( 'pinapl' );
  pinapl.innerHTML += 'e';
}

var cnt = document.getElementById( 'cnt' );
cnt.addEventListener( 'click', addCnt );
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 6vw; /* setting vw value on HTML makes elements resize to viewport width */
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
ol {
  display: inline-block; /* making list element inline-block forces content to determine its width */
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
.cnt {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>apple</li>
  <li>banana</li>
  <li>lemon</li>
  <li id="pinapl">pineapple</li>
</ol>

<div id="cnt" class="cnt">
  click to add content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, in pure CSS you cannot tell "set the `font-size` so the longest word fits in viewport automatically". You'll need JavaScript, presumably FitText:

http://fittextjs.com/ / https://github.com/adactio/FitText.js